# Limitar valores en TextFormField en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo un formulario con varios campos TextFormField, y funciona sin problemas cuando envío los valores a través del respectivo botón.  Sin embargo, quisiera saber si es posible LIMITAR los valores recibidos a un número determinado (de 1 a 10 solamente, por ejemplo), e impedir el ingreso de caracteres distintos a números (no letras ni caracteres especiales), de modo que el formulario no pueda ser enviado si sucede una de las dos situaciones descritas.  Actualmente puedo validar si el campo en cuestión está vacío, a través de la función:

```
validator: (value) {
  if (value.isEmpty) {
     return 'Ingrese el numero';
  }
  return null;
}
```

Pero no logro hacer las otras dos validaciones indicadas: que solamente admita números, y de estos solamente un rango específico.  Agradezco su colaboración.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para forzar a las restricciones que mencionas, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```dart
    TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      validator: (value) {
        final intNumber = int.tryParse(value);
        if (intNumber != null && intNumber <= 10){
          return null;
        }
        return 'Ingrese el numero';
      },
      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
    );
```

No te olvides de importar `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Comment: Gracias Diego, logré restringir solamente el ingreso de datos a solamente números con:

`código`
inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
`código`

Pero la otra restricción aún no la consigo: NO se trata de poder ingresar hasta 10 caracteres, SINO de solamente poder ingresar los números 1,2,3..... hasta 10, y que en caso de por ejemplo ingresar 20, aparezca el respectivo mensaje de error, como en la validación que tengo si el campo es vacío, según indiqué en la especificación de la pregunta.  Agradezco tu colaboración

Comment: revisa mi código actualizado, espero te sirva

Comment: Listo Diego, ya está la otra restricción.  Pero hay que utilizar para restringir a solamente ingreso de dígitos WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly 
en vez de FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly 
Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Ya està deprecado https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/WhitelistingTextInputFormatter-class.html   si te sirvió la respuesta marcalo como aceptada :)

Comment: No había visto el deprecated indicado.  Sin embargo funciona, no de la otra forma, incluso me genera error desde vscode

Comment: Hmm que version de flutter tienes

Comment: Sí, debe ser por eso.  Tengo la "Flutter 1.17.3".  La última vez que actualicé la versión luego nada servía y debí "downgradearla".  Si me animo la actualizo para evitar deprecateds jejeje :)

Comment: Dale  :) está bien